# Data add query in sql table

Tags: sql

How to add new data (multiple rows) in sql table without deleting existing data. My table is:

```
id   Location  Name   User ID LogDate      LogTime

1    Mumbai    Shanks   0001   11-Aug-09   15:15:20    
1    Mumbai    Shanks   0001   11-Aug-09   15:25:28    
1    Mumbai    Shanks   0001   11-Aug-09   16:35:56    
2    Delhi     Mahen    0002   11-Aug-09   02:25:50
```

This table is used for Time attendance for employees.

Comment: Hi,
i presume tha you are using MSSQL but still i don't understand you
INSERT INTO talbe1 ( ID, location name, user id, logDate, logTime )
Values( ... )
this inserts new data and now data i deleted if the problem is with something else pls explain further
Best Regards,
Iordan

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear on what you want to do.  Would you like to use existing values in the table to compute new values and then add that to the table?  You might want to tag this with sql as well (I can't yet due to my rep).